# Nested list comprehensions: if/for, not for/if

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you create a nested list comprehension like this:

```
if (dict.get(key) != None):
    for i in dict.get(key):
        #expression
```

Instead of this:

```
for i in dict.get(key):
    if (dict.get(key) != None):
        #expression
```

(dict.get(key) will give a list or none)

In essence, I want to iterate through the list only if the value for the key is not `None`. Is this possible with list comprehensions?

EDIT0:

What I have now: `dl = [str(d.get('title')) for d in info.get('director')[0:10]]`

- `info` is an IMDbPy Person object, which acts like a dictionary (keys & values)
- the key `director` sometimes does not exist, and that is what I would like to test for being  `None`
- if `director` does exist, it should return a list of IMDbPy Movie objects (also with keys & values), which are what I am getting the `title` of
- it should return a list of strings, or a list with one element: the string "None"

EDIT1:

Test case:

```
# this should work, as the key exists
my_dict = {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 40, 'times': [{h1: 1, m1: 1, h2: 0, m2: 59}, {h1: 2, m1: 3, h2: 2, m2: 57}]}

list_comp = [str(x.get('h1')) for x in my_dict.get('times')]

# but what if I try to get a value for a non-existent key?
list_comp1 = [str(x.get('h1')) for x in my_dict.get('time')]
```

`my_dict.get('time')` will return a `NoneType` object, but how can I detect that?

`list_comp` should give `['1', '2']` and `list_comp1` should give `['None']`

Comment: The purpose of list comprehension is to create a new list. Are you trying to create one?

Comment: What do you want the result to be if the condition is not met?  You can do `if blah: someList = [f(i) for i in blah]`.

Comment: What do you want the value of the list comprehension to be if key isn't in there?

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner It would be great if you provide sample input and output for the operation.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky edited. I hope I explained it better.

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner Words are often misleading. Simple test case, showing input and expected output, or more of these, would explain better.

Comment: Something like `[f(i) for i in dict.get(key)] if dict.get(key) is not None else ["None"]`?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky see EDIT1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From my earlier comment:*

The following expressions should evaluate to what you asked for (if you include the quotes around `'h1'` in your dict):

```
list_comp = [str(x.get('h1')) for x in my_dict.get('times')]
            if my_dict.get('times') is not None else ['None']

list_comp1 = [str(x.get('h1')) for x in my_dict.get('time')]
             if my_dict.get('time') is not None else ['None']
```